# Parsing Pirate Bay using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, parsing, xpath, html-agility-pack

I want to know how can I parse this respective website http://thepiratebay.sx/ using HTMLAgilityPack in C# and XPath?

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("http://thepiratebay.sx/");
```

this my code but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Load` reads the content from file or stream. To load the content from an *url*, Use

```
var web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://thepiratebay.sx/");
```